# view website running on local machine via android

Tags: c#, android, web-services, ipv4

I have a webservice in c# ,I want to access it via my android device through adhoc , I am able to get it in emulator using 10.0.2.2; but can't see on android device, Kindly suggest me any method to access that.

This is online webservice on w3school i am able to access it via my android device

```
  private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
  private final String URL =     "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
  private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
 private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
```

This is url of my local webservice http://localhost:63693/Notif.asmx
unable to access via android phone , though in emultor it is working
http://10.0.2.2:63693/Notif.asmx

Comment: Are you typing the direction with http:// header?

Comment: no only    192.168.1.180:63693/Notif.asmx

Comment: Well, then try `http://192.168.1.180:63693/Notif.asmx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to turn windows feature on . Go to -> Control Panel -> Add or Remove Program -> Turn Windows feature on or off -> .Net framework 4.5 advanced service -> WCF Services -> HTTP Activation . Enable this and Restart ur PC .

Use adhoc on android and connect your machine to it, simply use MachineIP:PortNo/Webservice.asmx

For custom IP - Enable IIS in turn features on or off .Run inetmgr via administrator and add your website there after that right Click edit bindings use IP or hostname whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your webservice on localhost then you can run it in emulator using address `http://10.0.2.2:63693/Notif.asmx`.

And if you want to run it live on phone then either you have to host your service on some Server.

For accessing localhost service on live phone, the phone and service(machine on which service is being hosted locally) must run on same Private network. You need to then call the Private address of machine from android app. With Private address, I mean **IPv4 address of machine**.
E.g., `http://192.168.1.180:63693/Notif.asmx`

You can get IPv4 of machine from **ipconfig** command in **cmd**.

Comment: I created adhoc from android and joined lan on my laptop, after that used ipconfig and http://192.168.43.183:8080/Notif.asmx but it says permission denied

Comment: Well that was not the way that was suggested as answer. It should work but why did you do it in this way?

Comment: @KunwarSingh, change your port number from **8080** to **63693**

Comment: changed port number also , still says invalid host name  .. any permissions required

Comment: @greenapps, what alternative you suggest for the same? This solution worked for me.

Comment: does it matter that adhoc should be created via machine or android device

Comment: Of course it worked for you. For me too. But OP did not do what you suggested. Instead he made a hotspot of his android device and connected his laptop with the device.

Comment: did you deployed using visual studio or via IIS server

Comment: `does it matter that adhoc should be created via machine or android device` Why are you asking? Normally your laptop/pc is connected to a router. And your android device too to the same -wifi- router.

Comment: Do you have this in you manifest file? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

Comment: The service i developed was on Java and I deployed it on **Tomcat Server**.

Comment: it worked simply    like this  http://192.168.43.183/Notif.asmx  via adhoc   thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the website on your device then your PC and your android device should be on same network and same subnet.

Then **yourIP:port** in address in url you can access your website on your android device